# How to make an array from a string using a loop?

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I have the following values:

```
$attached_products = "1,4,3";
```

I want to make an array that looks like:

```
$selected = array(1, 4, 3);
```

using a loop with my `$attached_products`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This could be done with a loop, but there's a simpler way.

You can break your string up around the commas using the `explode` function<sup>[[php docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)]</sup>. This will give you an array of strings of digits. You can convert each string to an integer by applying `intval`<sup>[[php docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php)]</sup> using `array_map`<sup>[[php docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)]</sup>.

```
$attached_products = "1,4,3";
$selected_strings = explode(',', $attached_products); # == array('1', '4', '3')
$selected = array_map('intval', $selected_strings);   # == array(1, 4, 3)
```

Comment: thanks for your response @Jeremy Banks, hmmm is that output equal to array(1, 4, 3)?

Comment: @Emkey: My values were strings, not integers. I've fixed that. Now they are the same.

Answer (score 4):

You use `explode()` for that:

```
$selected = explode(", ", $attached_products);
```

Answer (score 2):

If there may or may not be whitespace after the comma, you could use `preg_split()`.

```
$selected = preg_split(/,\s*/, $attached_products);
```

Alternatively you could use `explode()`, `trim()` and `array_map()`.

```
$selected = array_map('trim', explode(',', $attached_products));
```

If they must be integers, map them through `intval()`.